# pgfplots: add tikz drawing to axis labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

So far, I used `gnuplot` to draw plots for my LaTeX documents. However, sometimes it is not so satisfactory and I have not yet found the optimal solution for making plots. Since I read about `pgfplots` now and then here on Tex.SE, I want to try that. The Syntax is quite difficult for a Beginner, so I was unable to figure out how to do the following. Consider this MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        grid=both,
        grid style={line width=0.2pt, dashed, color=black},
        xlabel=xlabel,
        ylabel=ylabel]
    \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
        (2,-2.8559703)
        (3,-3.5301677)
        (4,-4.3050655)
        (5,-5.1413136)
        (6,-6.0322865)
        (7,-6.9675052)
        (8,-7.9377747)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which I mostly copied from the `pgfplots` manual. I want to add small arrows to the `$x$` and `$y$` axis labels, as in the following plot

[image: example plot]

which I made with `gnuplot`. In gnuplot, I added the small arrows with the aid of TikZ, and I would like to have my pgfplot to have a very similar style (arrows, grid lines etc).

I tried to add the arrows to the axis as follows:

```
xlabel=\tikz{\draw[>=latex,->,line width=0.2mm] node[left] {Gas / $\mathrm{\frac{kg \cdot J}{m^2}}$} (0,0) -- ++(0.5,0)},
```

however, that does not work at all. How should I change my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposal nests `tikzpicture`s, which should be avoided. Try

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        grid=both,
        grid style={line width=0.2pt, dashed, color=black},
        xlabel=xlabel, xlabel style={alias=aux},
        ylabel=ylabel,  ylabel style={alias=auy}]
    \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
        (2,-2.8559703)
        (3,-3.5301677)
        (4,-4.3050655)
        (5,-5.1413136)
        (6,-6.0322865)
        (7,-6.9675052)
        (8,-7.9377747)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \draw[-latex] (auy.east) -- ++(0,0.5);
    \draw[-latex] ([xshift=1mm]aux.east) -- ++(0.8,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

instead. Please note that, if you rotate the y label, the meaning of `east`, `north` etc. will change, you may then do something like `\draw[-latex] (aux.north) -- ++(0,0.5);` instead. Note also that after the axis is "done", there is the `current axis` node, whose anchors you many use, as well as `xticklabel cs` and so on (see section 4.9 of the pgfplots manual).

Comment: yay! this is exactly how I wanted it. Thanks! actually, I don't want to rotate the y axis label - I want all labels to have horizontal text.